# AngularJS ng-repeat-start ng-repeat-end with table and dynamic rowspan for two rows

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to get the data to be displayed as in below table.  Can someone please provide me how to write in html using angular js object data.  May be using ng-repeat-start but I couldnt understand how to achieve this. Please help

[image]

And I have my table with below data which I have to display as above in image. Can someone please provide me the format of object and how to display the same on html.

Whenever I click on configure it should display header and its value rows, accordingly both rule and line span should increase.
[image]

Comment: can you include sample data in your question please

Comment: I have added exact data. @NTP Please check.

Comment: Please suggest  me how to create the object inorder to display the data as in above table.

Comment: I like the drawn layout mockup, but when it comes to code or data structures, please include them as text instead of an image. No one wants to sit there and transcribe a JSON object when trying to help someone with an issue.